# /usr/bin/time and time in multicore platform

Tags: linux, shell, time, multicore

guys. I am confused about the result below:

1). **time xxxxx**

```
 real 0m28.942s
 user 0m28.702s
 sys 0m0.328s
```

2). **/usr/bin/time -p xxxxx**

```
real 28.48
user 0.00
sys 0.13
```

so. I have some question(user: 0m28.702s != 0, sys: 0m0.328s != 0.13):

1. what's different between time and /usr/bin/time ?
2. what's different in differnt cpu platform, one core or multicore ?

any suggestion？

Comment: Telling the exact command may help — since the former is a built-in and may execute other built-ins/aliases, while the latter is an external program and will only execute other programs.

Comment: The former(time) use built-in command, and the latter use an external program(/usr/bin/time). I guess this is common enviroment.

Comment: I meant what `xxxxx` is.

Comment: sorry, heh, this is aa command. xxxxx = sed -n 's/0//g' test.data.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to find out the answer to your first question using `type`:

```
$ type time
time is a shell keyword
$ type /usr/bin/time
/usr/bin/time is /usr/bin/time
```

So the first command uses a bash built-in, while the latter defers to an external program. However, not knowing what system you are using, I have no idea where that program comes from. On Gentoo Linux, there's no `/usr/bin/time` by default, and the only implementation available is [GNU time](http://www.gnu.org/directory/time.html) that has different output.

---

That said, I have tried a command similar to yours (assuming it's working on a 1G file), and got the following results:

```
$ time sed -e 's/0//g' big-file > big-file2

real    0m40.600s
user    0m31.295s
sys     0m4.174s

$ /usr/bin/time sed -e 's/0//g' big-file > big-file2
35.06user 3.31system 0:40.58elapsed 94%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3488maxresident)k
8inputs+2179176outputs (0major+276minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

As you can see, the numbers are similar.

Then, given your results (`0` userspace time is quite impossible) I'd say that your `/usr/bin/time` is simply broken. This might be worth reporting a bug to its author.